# How to display @ symbol in Vash

Tags: node.js, vash

I have a standard view in a NodeJs application.

There are no problems with the code, and the website is working as designed. I do have a minor problem when the page renders. I have tried many known escape characters but I have not managed to tell the view to ignore the @ symbol.

In Vash like Razor the model to view is an @ symbol so when I display an email address in the view for example test@test.com it takes 'test.com' as part of the model which is being sent to the view rather than the email address being displayed as plain html.

Is there an escape character to get around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Github read me says: https://github.com/kirbysayshi/vash#the-transition-character

```
Vash uses the @ symbol to transition between code and markup.
To escape and print a literal @, use a double @, like this: @@.
```

If that doesn't work, use the html entity: & # 6 4 ;
So: test & # 6 4 ;test.com. (without spaces).